# codeigniter open controller in fancybox popup

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, popup, fancybox

I am developing a website with codeignite . I have problem with submiting forms in fancy box popups .

Consider this is original page :

http://mysite/admin/blog/posts

I want to open comments page in fancy box popup

but when I want to delete a comment in popup box , the pop up closes and original page redirects to :

http://mysite/admin/comments/delete/5

How can I submit or open links in popup without closing the popup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have similar needs to your case. When i work it out with fancybox, i set the type to ajax it will close the box. So then i realize that there is still other support. We can use the iFrame type. When you use the iFrame, the url access is proceed inside the frame. So you might want see postprocess result from deleting data, isn't it? so you should consider change to iFrame.

resource :

1. http://fancybox.net/howto
2. http://fancybox.net/api
3. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 2):

You might also try this one for ur problem:

```
<a id="cmid" href="comments page url">View Comments</a>
```

Then your fancy box javascript code as like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $("#cmid").fancybox({
        'width'     : '50%',
        'height'    : '50%',
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'type'      : 'iframe'
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Then you do delete comment. I think this won't close the pop up window.